# Show undefined variable errors in Django templates?

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I ask Django to tell me when it encounters, for example, an undefined variable error while it's rendering templates?

I've tried the obvious `DEBUG = True` and `TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True`, but they don't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the django documentation,
undefined variables are treated as ''(empty string) by default. While in *if for regroup*, it's *None*.
If you are going to identify the variable undefined, change TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID in settings.
'%s' makes the invalid variable to be rendered as its variable name, in this way, u can identify easily.
[how-invalid-variables-are-handled](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables)

Comment: Another trick is to set TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID to "%s %s" and that will cause a formatting error to be raised.  For something cleaner, see my answer.

Comment: In newer Django version, use `string_if_invalid`.

Comment: You can add the following to your settings.py: `if DEBUG:
    TEMPLATES[0]["OPTIONS"]["string_if_invalid"] = "{{ %s }}"`, the nyou see each undefined variable as `{{variable }}`

Comment: @nerdoc thank you so much, that's such a useful trick!! using Django 4.2.5, I had to change it slightly to `... = "{{ %s }}"` i.e. pass a string rather than a tuple. but it works! will definitely always use that going forward

Answer (score 25):

Put this in your debug settings:

```
class InvalidString(str):
    def __mod__(self, other):
        from django.template.base import TemplateSyntaxError
        raise TemplateSyntaxError(
            "Undefined variable or unknown value for: \"%s\"" % other)

TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = InvalidString("%s")
```

This should raise an error when the template engine sees or finds an undefined value.

Comment: Be wary... this is really overkill, because a lot of in-built templates rely on undefined variables not throwing errors.

Comment: This does not seem to detect undefined foobar in `{% if foobar %}` or `{% for foo in foobar %}`

Comment: WARNING! Using this will completely break the `default:'<string>'` template filter that Django provides. No variable will ever be able to default to the specific string, because this causes every undefined variable to be converted to `''` before the `default` filter runs.

Comment: @coredumperror It would break the behaviour of the `default` tag, if it didn't raise an error first!

Answer (score 6):

### How to log a warning on undefined variable in a template

It seems that Django relies on undefined variables being a simple empty string. So instead of changing this behaviour or making it throw an exception, let's keep it the same but have it log a warning instead!

In your `settings.py` file:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        # ...
        'OPTIONS': {
            # ...
            'string_if_invalid': InvalidStringShowWarning("%s"),
        },
    }
]
```

(`string_if_invalid` replaces `TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID` in newer Django versions.)

And further up, you'll need to define the `InvalidStringShowWarning` class, making it behave while logging a warning:

```
class InvalidStringShowWarning(str):
    def __mod__(self, other):
        import logging
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.warning("In template, undefined variable or unknown value for: '%s'" % (other,))
        return ""

    def __bool__(self): # if using Python 2, use __nonzero__ instead
        # make the template tag `default` use its fallback value
        return False
```

You should be able to see the warning in the output of `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: @coredumperror Are you talking about `default_if_none` or `default` template tag? In any case, thanks for looking into this, this is something that needs to be tested.

Comment: I mean the `default` filter, which apparently only activates if the template var is, in fact, undefined. But this converts it from an undefined template var to an empty string, so `default` skips it. @Beau's solution works without messing up the `default` filter, though.

Comment: You're right. My answer does break the `default` filter for some reason. But your explanation isn't quite right. The `default` filter applies to the empty string, as well as any other falsey value, so it does work for some defined variables. This answer breaks `default` for some other reason.

Comment: Huh, you're right. I was misinterpreting what the `default` filter does. But then why does this solution break it? Something about that `%`, perhaps?

Comment: @coredumperror See my edit. It now works with `default`

Answer (score 6):

Finding template variables that didn't exist in the context was important to me as several times bugs made it into production because views had changed but templates had not.

I used this technique, implemented in `manage.py`, to achieve the effect of breaking tests when template variables not found in the context were used. Note that this technique works with `for` loops and `if` statements and not just `{{ variables }}`.

```
import sys

# sometimes it's OK if a variable is undefined:
allowed_undefined_variables = [
    'variable_1',
    'variable_2',
]

if 'test' in sys.argv:
    import django.template.base as template_base

    old_resolve = template_base.Variable.resolve

    def new_resolve(self, context):
        try:
            value = old_resolve(self, context)
        except template_base.VariableDoesNotExist as e:
            # if it's not a variable that's allowed to not exist then raise a
            # base Exception so Nodes can't catch it (which will make the test
            # fail)
            if self.var not in allowed_undefined_variables:
                raise Exception(e)

            # re-raise the original and let the individual Nodes deal with it
            # however they'd like
            raise e

        return value

    template_base.Variable.resolve = new_resolve
```

Comment: Great answer! i have also added smart skip logic based on template path
```skipped_templates = ('rest_framework', 'django');  tpl = context.template.name; if tpl and tpl.startswith(skipped_templates):
            raise e```

Comment: This is the correct way to tweak this system! By monkey patching `django.template.base.Variable.resolve` with a function that does something extra when `VariableDoesNotExist` is thrown, then re-raises it, you can insert yourself into the system without otherwise affecting the behavior of the system. e.g. Replacing the `allowed_undefined_variables` stuff with code that simply logs `self.var` so you know when an undefined variable got used.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that's a major oversight on Django's part and the primary reason I prefer not to use their default template engine. The sad truth is that, at least for now (Django 1.9), **you can't achieve this effect reliably**.

- You **can** make Django raise an exception when `{{ undefined_variable }}` is encountered - by using "the hack" described in slacy's answer.
- You **can't** make Django raise the same exception on `{% if undefined_variable %}` or `{% for x in undefined_variable %}` etc. "The hack" doesn't work in such cases.
- Even in cases in which you can, it is strongly discouraged by Django authors to use this technique in production environment. Unless you're sure you don't use Django's built-in templates in your app, you should use "the hack" **only** in `DEBUG` mode.

However, if you're stuck with Django's templates for now, I would recommend to use slacy's answer, just make sure you're in `DEBUG` mode.

Answer (score 2):

Read up on [how invalid variable are handled](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#invalid-template-variables) in templates.  Basically, just set [TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#template-string-if-invalid) to something in your settings.py.

```
TEMPLATE_STRING_IF_INVALID = "He's dead Jim! [%s]"
```

Comment: This works okay, but there are places where these strings will kind of disappear into the noise (in a <head> block, for example).

Comment: Are you looking for the system to throw an exception?  If not you can view source for items in non-display blocks.

Answer (score 1):

**I am use next:**

```
import logging

from django.utils.html import format_html
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


class InvalidTemplateVariable(str):
    """
    Class for override output that the Django template system
    determinated as invalid (e.g. misspelled) variables.
    """

    # styles for display message in HTML`s pages
    styles = mark_safe('style="color: red; font-weight: bold;"')

    def __mod__(self, variable):
        """Overide a standart output here."""

        # access to current settings
        from django.conf import settings

        # display the message on page in make log it only on stage development
        if settings.DEBUG is True:

            # format message with captured variable
            msg = 'Attention! A variable "{}" does not exists.'.format(variable)

            # get logger and make
            logger = self.get_logger()
            logger.warning(msg)

            # mark text as non-escaped in HTML
            return format_html('<i {}>{}</i>', self.styles, msg)

        # on production it will be not displayed
        return ''

    def get_logger(self):
        """Create own logger with advanced error`s details."""

        logger = logging.getLogger(self.__class__.__name__)

        logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

        formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s')

        handler.setFormatter(formatter)

        logger.addHandler(handler)

        return logger
```

**Usage in settings file (by default it settings.py):**

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        ......
        'OPTIONS': {
            .....................
            'string_if_invalid': InvalidTemplateVariable('%s'),
            .....................
        },

    },
]
```

**or directly**

```
TEMPLATES[0]['OPTIONS']['string_if_invalid'] = InvalidTemplateVariable('%s')
```

A result if DEBUG = True:

**On page**

[image]

**In console**

```
> System check identified 1 issue (0 silenced). October 03, 2016 -
> 12:21:40 Django version 1.10.1, using settings 'settings.development'
> Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/ Quit the server
> with CONTROL-C. 2016-10-03 12:21:44,472 - InvalidTemplateVariable -
> WARNING - Attention! A variable "form.media" does not exists.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [pytest-django setting](https://pytest-django.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuring_django.html#pytest-ini-settings) FAIL_INVALID_TEMPLATE_VARS

The invaild vars get checked if pytest executes the code.

```
[pytest]
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE = mysite.settings
FAIL_INVALID_TEMPLATE_VARS = True
```

Answer (score -4):

If there is a undefined variable in templates, django won't tell you.

You can print this variable in view.

Comment: Apparently this is not true; see, eg, wilio's comment.