# Raise error in a strict mode for Django templates

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I don't know if it's a Django or just python question but, how to active a "strict" mode in django/python ? When i use an unknown variable in a template, no error gets raised. Is it possible to cause these errors to get raised?

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15312135/how-to-make-django-template-raise-an-error-if-a-variable-is-missing-in-context